# display more that one column in listbox, winforms

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I'm using bindinglist and listbox datasource to populate listobox,

```
BindingList<MyData> data = new BindingList<MyData>();
listbox1.DataSource = data;
listbox.DisplayMember = "Name";
```

Question is, how can I add more than this one column (Name)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ListBox` supports only one 'column' and you can't add more display members. Thus I suggest you to use `DataGridView` instead of `ListBox`. Add two columns of `DataGridViewTextBoxColumn` type and make them read-only. Then provide `DataPropertyName` values for each column to be bound to your data type.

Another option (which I *do not recommend*) is creating property on your `MyData` class which will return some sort of concatenated string for two properties.

Comment: ListView set in Details-view is also an alternative for a UI control with more than one column and it also supports data binding.